# Replace character with preg replace

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have been trying to replace/ remove any special characters when added in the form below. Characters like: +-()*&^%$#@!~

I have been trying to do this with preg replace but im not able to get it working. Code which i wrote is below. Am i missing something?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="kenteken.php">
<input type="text" name="kenteken" />
<input type="submit" name="verzend" value="Check kenteken" />
</form>
<?php
// Include de benodigde classes
include_once 'api/loader.php';

// Kijken of er een kenteken is ingevoerd.
if(!isset($_POST["kenteken"])) {
    echo 'Geen kenteken ontvangen. Ga terug er probeer opnieuw!';
    exit;
} else {
// Witte characters (spaties) weghalen
    $k = trim($_POST["kenteken"]);
    $k2 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $k);
// Kijken of kenteken leeg is met spaties
    if(empty($k2)) {
        echo 'Geen kenteken ingevoerd. Ga terug er probeer opnieuw!';
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: http://domain.nl/kenteken/?kenteken=$k2");
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the sole purpose to make a usable url for the redirect?

Comment: ["Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi @The avon guy, yes it needs to redirect to an url. Example when a user posts 46-hps-1 it needs to return a url like: domain.com/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('46HPS1')?$format=json

Comment: The `header` will never work with content already being output. You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php, then the special characters would be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$k2 = preg_replace('/[^[:alnum:]]/', '', $k);
```

simple and quick ;)